# Sonar 4.5.1 Custom Rules: No Java XPath Rule Template after Sonar Upgrade

Tags: java, sonarqube

I updated Sonar from 4.3 to 4.5.1. After this update I missed my Java XPATH Custom Rules. All of this custom rules are in state "REMOVED" in the rules table of the Sonar database.

I dont know how to reactivate them or how to create new custom Java XPATH rules in Sonar 4.5.1.

I know that the custom rule concept changed a little bit in Sonar 4.4 and that I can find rule templates in the new "Rule" section. But there is no Java XPATH Rule Template.
There is only one XPATH Template for Javascript.